# ffmpeg Не определяет разрешение видео

Tags: php, видео, ffmpeg, конвертация

Получаю высоту и ширину видеофайла:

```
$ffmpeg = new ffmpeg_movie($file);

    $w = $ffmpeg->getFrameWidth();

    $h = $ffmpeg->getFrameHeight();
```

В некоторых файлах не определяет размеры, и возвращает 0. Остальные параметры определяет: продолжительность, количество кадров и тд. В чем причина, и как поступить в этом случае?

Comment: может проблема в кодеке? возможно не все файлы заточены под ffmpeg кодек

Comment: попробуйте эти файлы скормить обычному ffmpeg или ffprobe.

Comment: @fonjeekay, под "скормить", вы подразумеваете вытащить эти параметры через консоль? конвертируются файлы ffmpeg нормально.

Comment: @РоманМальцев я не знаю API PHP-обёртки, но, после открытия в обычном API нужно вызывать `avformat_find_stream_info()` иначе вполне можно словить ситуацию с чем-то недоинициализированным. Как делается тут. Чисто прикола ради, можно попытаться получить один фрейм и попытаться потом прочитать эти значения заново или из фрейма (например в MPEG-TS размер фрейма в течении файла может меняться - ожидаемое поведение)